# Do non const internal members of class become const when I have const ref to an object of that class?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Well, I think my problem originates in a lake of knowledge of basic C++ concepts. The problem is, in my code (below) I have the classes Header and Register. For both, I pass a reference to a ifstrem file already opened. The Header reads some bytes from it. Register has a method to return a reference of Header (which is passed in Register constructor).

The problem is, when I declare the reference to Header as const (in my Register class), I've got an error message saying:

```
error C2662: 'Header::Field_1' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Header' to 'Header &'
```

The problem, I guess, is:

Field_1 method changes the file cursor through seekg. therefore this member object cannot be const (its internal structure is being changed). Being fstream _stream declared inside Header class, and having a const reference for this class does it make all its internal members const as well?

PS: I'm using VS C++ express. The code below doesn't do anything useful, is just an example.

```
// ********** HEADER.H ***********
#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__

#include <fstream>

class Header
{
    private:

        std::ifstream* _stream;
        unsigned long field1;

    public:

        Header(std::ifstream* stream);
        ~Header() { }

        unsigned long Field_1(void);
};

class Register
{
    private:
        const Header& _header;
        std::ifstream* _stream;

    public:

        Register(const Header& header, std::ifstream* stream);
        ~Register(){ }

        const Header& GetHeader(void) { return _header; }
};

#endif /*__HEADER_H__*/

//********* PROGRAM.CPP *************

#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

Header::Header(ifstream* stream) : _stream(stream)
{
}

unsigned long Header::Field_1(void)
{
    _stream->seekg(0x00, fstream::beg);
    _stream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&field1), sizeof(field1));
    return field1;
}


Register::Register(const Header& header, std::ifstream* stream): _header(header), _stream(stream)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    ifstream file("test.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    Header h(&file);
    Register reg(h, &file);

    cout << "Field 1 " << reg.GetHeader().Field_1() << endl;

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `Register::GetHeader(void)` to be returning a *const* `Header&` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when `GetHeader()` returns a const reference to the Header object, you can only call const methods on it.
In this case if you declare `Field_1`as a const method by writing:

```
unsigned long Header::Field_1(void) const
```

(note the const on the end)

The trouble is if you do this then *within* the const method all other members appear as if they are const too (unless you mark them as mutable).

As a result you will probably have trouble with the `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&field1)`.

In which case the simplest solution is probably to have `GetHeader()` return a non-const reference. Alternatively you could mark `field1` as [`mutable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword) (but make sure you understand the semantics and dangers of `mutable` first if you go down that route. My feeling is that making `GetHeader()` return a non const reference is what you really want here)

Answer (score 2):

The `Register::GetHeader()` function returns a `const Header &`.  Therefore you cannot call any non-const member functions through this reference.

To fix your problem, i expect you want to make the `Header::Field_1()` function const.

ie. declared as `unsigned long Field_1(void) const;`