# What's the use of const here

Tags: c++, constants

in

`int salary() const { return mySalary; }`

as far as I understand const is for this pointer, but I'm  not sure. Can any one tell me what is the use of const over here?

Comment: You're exactly right, it affects the this*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you've got the right idea, in C++ const on a method of an object means that the method cannot modify the object.

For example, this would not be allowed:

```
class Animal {
   int _state = 0;

   void changeState() const { 
     _state = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: This syntax is only valid for C++0x

Comment: Which syntax?  I haven't typed any C++ in a while, so perhaps I got something slightly wrong, no guarantees it compiles, but overlooking any mistakes I'm sure you get the general idea, and the general idea is part of regular C++.

Comment: I could be mistaken, I was using MSVC++ version 6 (years ago), perhaps it didn't conform to the spec, does Microsoft ever do anything like that? ;)

Comment: Under C++-98: §9.3.3: "A nonstatic member function may be declared const, volatile, or const volatile. These cv-qualifiers affect the type of the this pointer (9.3.2)." Therefore, that code snippet should produce an error.

Comment: I was referring to the instance member initialization, this is new for C++0x.

Comment: Alex has been doing C#, I'd guess.  But the idea is the same.

Comment: @ergosys: ah, thanks.  I've been doing C# and Scala recently, the C++ knowledge is getting overwritten!

Comment: Note: any member variables marked `mutable` can be changed through a `const` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword

Answer (score 5):

When the function is marked `const` it can be called on a const pointer/reference of that class. In effect it says **This function does not modify the state of the class**.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `const` method. It means that it won't modify the member variables of the class nor will it call non-`const` methods. Thus:

```
const foo bar;
bar.m();
```

is legal if `m` is a `const` method but otherwise wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

It means that function can be called on a const object; and inside that member function the `this` pointer is const.

Answer (score 0):

It just guarantees that calling salary() doesn't change the object state.  IE, it can be called with a const pointer or reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's a const member function. It's a contract that the function does not change the state of the instance.

more here: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-memberfuncs/constmemberfuncs.html

Answer (score 0):

A const after function of a class, means this function would not modify any member objects of this class. 
Only one exception, when the member variable is marked with Mutable.