# c++ const use in class methods

Tags: c++, constants

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the use of const here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025159/whats-the-use-of-const-here)
>   [Using 'const' in class's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157458/using-const-in-classs-functions)

Hi All,
I keep making mistakes about the use of const with class methods and variables. For example, sometimes I fix problems using

```
const int myfunc(const int &obj) const { }
```

some other times I feel I don't need const at the end since the parameter is already const, so I don't see why I should enforce this fact by appending a const at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const int myfunc(const int &obj) const { }`

1. The first `const` indicates that the return value is constant.  In this particular case, it's not particularly relevant since the `int` is a value as opposed to a reference.
2. The second `const` indicates the parameter `obj` is constant.  This indicates to the caller that the parameter will not be modified by the function.
3. The third `const` indicates the function `myfunc` is constant.  This indicates to the caller that the function will not modify non-mutable member variables of the class to which the function belongs.

Regarding #3, consider the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    void Func1()       { ... }  // non-const member function
    void Func2() const { ... }  //     const member function
};

MyClass c1;        // non-const object
const MyClass c2;  //     const object

c1.Func1();  // fine...non-const function on non-const object
c1.Func2();  // fine...    const function on non-const object
c2.Func1();  // oops...non-const function on     const object (compiler error)
c2.Func2();  // fine...    const function on     const object
```

Answer (score 4):

Noel Llopis wrote a great chapter on const in C++ for Game Developers.

Take a look at his blog post http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-const-nazi for a good explanation of const.

Answer (score 0):

The const at the end indicates the const'ness of a member variable with respect to a class. It indicates it does not change any of the state of a class. The const at the beginning indicates the const'ness of the type int.