# C++ keyword mutable

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ ‘mutable’ keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword)

What does the keyword `mutable` do in the following C++ code:

```
class X {
   mutable int x;
...
};
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/

Answer (score 1):

mutable keyword allows you to modify particular attribute of a constant object ... check [this](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html)