# C++ language some live examples for mutable

Tags: c++, constants, volatile, mutable

Can someone show a live example of the usage of `mutable` keyword, when it is used in a `const` function and explain in a live example about the `mutable` and `const` function and also difference for the `volatile` member and function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword

Answer (score 6):

You can use mutable for variables that are allowed to be modified in const object instances. This is called logical constness (opposed to bitwise constness) as the object has not changed from the user's point of view.

You can for example cache the length of a string to increase performance.

```
class MyString
{
public:
...

const size_t getLength() const
{
    if(!m_isLenghtCached)
    {
         m_length = doGetLength();
         m_isLengthCached = true;
    }

    return m_length;    
}

private:
sizet_t doGetLength() const { /*...*/ }
mutable size_t m_length;
mutable bool m_isLengthCached;
};
```

Comment: other place I use them is in iterators, where const refers to iterator values, rather than iterator index (which must be mutable)

Comment: so you define const iterators to be const_iterators... I never understood why there were two different types.

Comment: @Alexandre: Because the constness of the iterator and the constness of the value it references are two very different things.

Comment: yes I pretty much understand that. But your solution is more consistent with the behaviour of T* and const T*, and I don't understand why STL designers didn't introduce const iterator = const_iterator semantics in the first place.

Comment: @Alex: `const iterator = const_iterator` is equivalent to `T* const = const T*`, which is invalid for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutable on a counter tracking the number of time a Class member is accessed through a const accessor.

Answer (score 1):

I used it once to implement [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).