# In Java, when do you use const instead of final?

Tags: java, constants, final

It seems these two are identical.   Does one improve performance over the other for read only variables?

```
const ant;
final ant;
```

Comment: No they aren't. `const` is a syntax error, wherever used in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` (and `goto`) is [never used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). It's just a reserved keyword in Java.

Note that when using `const` (or `goto`) the code doesn't even compile.

More info:

- [Why const keyword is not used in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428358/why-const-keyword-is-not-used-in-java)
- [Why there is no constant keyword in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735736/why-is-there-no-constant-keyword-in-java)