# whats the purpose of "const" keyword?

Tags: java

Why `const` is a reserved keyword in Java but has no function? If they decided to use `final` instead then whats the point of having `const`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no Constant keyword in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735736/why-is-there-no-constant-keyword-in-java)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: To me, that seems like a totally different question (it's about semantics, whereas this one is purely about the keyword).

Answer (score 13):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used. **This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.**

By way of historical perspective, I can offer you the following [quote](http://web.archive.org/web/20030808110023/http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/community/chat/JavaLive/2003/jl0729.html) by [Josh Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) from 2003:

> Josh Bloch: We do not have plans to add support for the `const` keyword to the Java language. It was a mixed blessing in C++; as you know, it's merely advisory, and can cast on or off. Gosling hated it, and did `final` instead. What you really want is "immutable," but it's a research problem to make this work properly.

Comment: Yea ... but see my answer :-)

Comment: @StephenC: I am no Java historian. However, I don't think Bloch using the word "hate" when describing Gosling's attitude towards `const` is consistent with the latter "keeping his options open". :-)

Comment: I think Bloch meant that Gosling hated the way that `const` was implemented in C++ ... not the actual keyword.   Besides, Gosling was part of a team. Block saying "it is a research problem to make it work properly" is (IMO) consistent with them making `const` a reserved word to keep their options open ... and not doing the same for `struct`, `union` and so on.

Comment: @StephenC: Perhaps. At any rate, we both are speculating and will probably never know the actual ex ante thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to ask the pre Java 1.0 designers to find out their *original* motivation, but I would surmise that they were simply keeping their options open.  The `goto` reserved word is another example.

My guess is that the text that "aix" found in the JLS is a "postfacto" rationalization.  Why?  Because `struct`, `union`, `unsigned` and so on are NOT reserved words in Java!  In short, I don't buy it ... no matter what the JLS claims :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

"The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used."

i don't know about the exact background but maybe they used to be part of java?

Answer (score 1):

It is **just reserved keyword**. It does not have any use case or functionality

Answer (score 0):

> It is thought that the reservation of the keyword occurred to allow for an extension of the Java language to include C++-style const methods and pointer to const type. The enhancement request ticket in the Java Community Process for implementing const correctness in Java was closed in 2005, implying that const correctness will probably never find its way into the official Java specification.

Answer (score 0):

From JLS -

"The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs"