# Usage of the Java keyword const

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no Constant keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735736/why-is-there-no-constant-keyword-in-java)

I recently started developing in *Java* and I was wondering why the keyword `const` wasn't implemented and you had to use a rather long constant definition in a class:

```
protected static final String VALIDATION_ERROR = "validationError";
```

Instead of the expected way

```
const VALIDATION_ERROR = "validationError"
```

Is there anyone who can point me out why you have to use (or hasn't made it in the current syntax) the *former* instead of the *later* since the *later* is assuming the *former*?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, it answers perfectly my interrogation, my bad for not searching enough beforehand

Comment: So whats the `TODO` now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java `final` == `const`

The other keywords (`protected` & `static`) are doing things in addition to defining the constant (defining the scope)

Answer (score 3):

final String is enough, protected and static showing the scope of the constant.