# Using References in const Methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants, const-correctness

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class LinkedList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int StoredValue;
        // ...
    };

    Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index)
    {
        // ...

        return NodeReference;
    }

    public:

    int Get(std::size_t Index) const
    {
        return GetNodeReference(Index).StoredValue;
    }
};
```

This won't compile because the `const` method `Get` uses `GetNodeReference`, which cannot be `const` because it returns a reference.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Do you control the code?  Could you make GetNodeReference return a const Node&?

Comment: @Jeff The idea is that I can use `GetNodeReference` for my setter as well as my getter, so the reference needs to be changeable.

Comment: In that case, the usual "overload on const" approach, as demonstrated in my answer, should work.

Comment: like an option, it should be possible to fix it declaring  "int StoredValue" as "mutable int StoredValue", this should allow modifying value from const method. Am I right? I've read it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/does-the-mutable-keyword-have-any-purpose-other-than-allowing-the-variable-to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could provide two overloads of `GetNodeReference`:

```
Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index)
{
    // ...

    return NodeReference;
}

const Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const
{
    // ...

    return NodeReference;
}
```

Note that the second overload has two `const` modifers, one at the beginning of the line for the return type and one at the end of the line for the implicitly passed `*this` object.

To avoid code repetition, you can implement the non-const overload based on the const overload:

```
const Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const
{
    // ...

    return NodeReference;
}

Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index)
{
    return const_cast<Node&>(static_cast<const LinkedList&>(*this).getNodeReference(Index));
}
```

This technique is discussed in Item 3 of *Effective C++* by Scott Meyers.

Comment: `GetNodeReference` is a private function. Is it necessary to write pair-functions?

Comment: If there is some code to produce the NodeReference, and that can be done in a const function, you can just refactor it to a separate function called from both overloads. To me it seems that the "avoid repetition trick" produces more source code rather than less. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't implement an indexed `Get` function for lists at all. It will be WAY too easy for a new developer to come in and use it in a loop, turning a linear interation into a polynomial iteration.

If you need such a capability, make a free-function that uses the builtin iterators of the list in conjunction with say `std::advance` to get the node you want.

If you absolutely need the member function, then the normal approach is the one suggested by @FredOverflow and use overloads (quote his code):

```
const Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const
{
    // ...

    return NodeReference;
}

Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index)
{
    return const_cast<Node&>(static_cast<const LinkedList&>(*this).getNodeReference(Index));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

> class LinkedList {
>
> private:
>
> ```
> struct Node
> {
>     int StoredValue;
>     // ...
> };
>
> Node NodeReference;
>
> const Node* const GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const
> {
>     return &NodeReference;
> }
> ```
>
> public:
>
> ```
> int Get(std::size_t Index) const
> {
>     const Node *const node = GetNodeReference(Index);
>     return node->StoredValue;
> }
> ```
>
> };

**Edit:**

As you can read in the comments

> const Node* const GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const () ...

should be changed to:

> const Node* GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const () ...

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting the signature.  What does the `const` immediately after `Node*` mean?

Comment: It means that neither the pointer (nor the content (first "const")) shall be changed.

Comment: @Max: In this context, it means nothing, because scalar return types cannot be `const`. The compiler ignores it.

Comment: Actually this could be done nicer, I put it in another answer though, otherwise the above question wouldn't make sense any more.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't know about your compiler, but if I try "node->StoredValue++;" I get a compiler error: "increment of data-member `LinkedList::Node::StoredValue' in read-only structure, which I believe is prove, that the first "const" is not ignored by my compiler.

Comment: @FredOverflow: If I try "node = 0;" my compiler says: "assignment of read-only variable `node'" which I believe to be prove, that the second const is not being ignored by my comiler.

Comment: The second `const` is superfluous **in the context of return types**. That is, the return types `const T*` and `const T* const` are completely identical, just as the return types `int` and `const int` are completely identical.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I must be understanding something completely wrong. If I put the line "node = 0;" in my code. Then if I use the second const or not, let's my compiler either compile or it gives me an error. How can it be superfluous then? And I believe this to be the case, because T* is a pointer, and the second const tells my compiler, that I don't want this pointer to be changed.

Comment: I'm **not** talking about the local variable `node`. Of course it makes a difference if a variable is `const` or not. I'm talking about the **return type** of the function `GetNodeReference`. You can change that to `const Node*` and it won't make any difference to the client. That is, `GetNodeReference(5) = 0` won't compile, no matter if the return type is `const Node*` or `const Node* const`. Again, I am only talking about the **return type** of the function, **not** the type of the local variable `node`. Do you understand now?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Wait...okay I understand it now. Thanks for pointing that out. And sorry that it took me so long. :-/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

> class LinkedList {
>
> private:
>
> ```
> struct Node
> {
>     int StoredValue;
>     // ...
> };
>
> Node NodeReference;
>
> const Node& GetNodeReference(std::size_t Index) const
> {
>     return NodeReference;
> }
> ```
>
> public:
>
> ```
> int Get(std::size_t Index) const
> {
>     const Node node = GetNodeReference(Index);
>     return node.StoredValue;
> }
> ```
>
> };