# Is X const &x == X & const x?

Tags: c++, constants

I understand that `X & const x` is redundant. It is not ok! But I want to know what is the difference between `X const &x` and `X & const x`? 
Is the first expression saying that x is a reference to a constant `class X` ?

Comment: How is `X & const x` redundant? Why it is not ok?

Comment: @VJo Because the standard says so.  Except in cases where it says it's OK.  (If the `const` is inserted as the result of a `typedef` or a template expansion, for example.)

Comment: How can something legal be equivalent to something illegal? :)

Comment: Ok, I see now. The question was formulated in a weird way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read it from right to left : `X& const x` - x is a constant reference to object of type X which doesn't make sense, references are constant by definition. `X const& x` - x is a reference to constant of type X.

Answer (score 6):

`X const &x` is a reference to a `const X`, while `X & const x` is illegal. There is no such thing as a `const` reference since references aren't `mutable` to begin with.

Comment: Ironically, putting "mutable" in `backticks` may be read as reference to the very real C++ keyword of that name, which allows one to [change `const` members from inside `const` objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword). Not that any of this would make "constant references" any more meaningful or legal (as far as I know, that is).

Comment: @delnan: I added the backticks as a force of habit since `mutable` is indeed a keyword. Should I remove them to avoid confusion?

Comment: Well, it may save a reader or two a second of wonder, but I only added my comment because I found the irony amusing.

Comment: @delnan: Let's go with irony then, its worth a second of wonder.

Answer (score 5):

References themselves are always constant. You cannot change the reference to refer to something else after initialization.

Yes first expression says that the referrence is referring a constant.

Answer (score 1):

`X const&` if a reference to an `X` which you are not allowed to modify through the reference. You can think of it as a read-only-view. Whether or not the `X` itself is `const` is not reflected in the reference type. Note that you can initialize `X const&` with *both* `const` and non-`const` objects:

```
X a;
X const b;
X const& r = a;   // read-only-view on non-const X
X const& s = b;   // read-only-view on const X
```

The important part is that you cannot change the `X` *through the reference*, but you *can* change `a` directly, and that change will be reflected via `r`.

`X& const` is forbidden by the standard since references themselves can never be modified, anyway.