# Why is Mutable keyword used

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ 'mutable' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/c-mutable-keyword)

```
class student {

   mutable int rno;

   public:
     student(int r) {
         rno = r;
     }
     void getdata() const {
         rno = 90;
     } 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to write (i.e. "mutate") to the `rno` member through a `student` member function even if used with a `const` object of type `student`.

```
class A {
   mutable int x;
   int y;

   public:
     void f1() {
       // "this" has type `A*`
       x = 1; // okay
       y = 1; // okay
     }
     void f2() const {
       // "this" has type `A const*`
       x = 1; // okay
       y = 1; // illegal, because f2 is const
     }
};
```

Comment: does the presence of any const member function make the member variables read only?

Comment: @IvinPoloSony: Yes and no. Just inside the member function(s) that have the `const` qualifier. Let me edit my answer ...

Comment: So for a const function to update a member variable it has to be mutable Right?. normal member functions can anyways edit member variables.

Comment: @IvinPoloSony: Exactly. However, note that this is extremely dirty. Using mutable is often an *indicator* that you're doing something wrong. It's not always the case (there are legitimate use cases for it) but often.

Answer (score 1):

The `mutable` keyword is used so that a `const` object can change fields of itself. In your example alone, if you were to remove the `mutable` qualifier, then you would get a compiler error on the line

```
rno = 90;
```

Because an object that is declared `const` cannot (by default) modify it's instance variables.

The only other workaround besides `mutable`, is to do a `const_cast` of `this`, which is very hacky indeed.

It also comes in handy when dealing with `std::map`s, which cannot be accessed using the index ing operator `[]` if they are const.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, it's used to lie and deceive.

```
student s(10);
```

You want data? Sure, just call `getdata()`.

```
s.getdata();
```

You thought you'd get data, but I actually changed `s.rno` to `90`. HA! And you thought it was safe, `getdata` being `const` and all...

Comment: I'm not sure that this style of post (rhetorical humor) is best for SO. I could understand on meta, but this seems almost insulting to the OP. For that reason, I have downvoted your post.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII well, I certainly see your point, but the question is `Why is Mutable keyword used`, and not `what does mutable mean`...