# C++ comparator function with lazy key generation

Tags: c++, stdmap

I want to store a objects with a custom comparator function in a C++ `std::map`, e.g.:

```
std::map<Part, Inventory, PartCmp>
```

For the comparator, I would like to sort the objects by a "key" that could be expensive to compute, so I thought about a lazy evaluation method. The below example is kind of trivial but illustrates the problem:

```
class Part {
public:
   std::string item_id;
   int color_id;
   int condition;
   std::string name;
   std::string category;

   std::string key();       
private:
   std::string key_;
}

std::string Part::key() {
    // Only create key value if it hasn't been done before
    if (key_.empty()) {
        ostringstream keystream;
        keystream << item_id << color_id << condition;
        key_ = keystream.str();
    }
    return key_;
}
```

This means my comparator looks this:

```
struct PartCmp {
    bool operator() (Part& p1, Part& p2) const {
        return p1.key() < p2.key();
    }
};
```

This is different from every other example I've seen where `p1` and `p2` are declared as `const` parameters.

However, in this case `p1` and `p2` cannot be declared as `const` since the `key()` method modify its respective objects. The code compiles but is this a bad thing to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to declare the field

```
private:
   mutable std::string key_;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105014/841108).

And also, as suggested by a comment from [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza), make your `key()` method `const`

At last, I believe you are more doing some [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), not some [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Comment: And make the `key()` method `const`.

Comment: Yes -- lazy generation (followed by caching) like this is one of the few cases where `mutable` really makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! Being new to C++ I hadn't come across this language feature yet. Works great.

Comment: Time for ["you don't know `const` and `mutable`"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/)!