# const before parameter vs const after function name in C++

Tags: c++, function, constants

What is the difference between something like this

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

and something like this

```
friend Circle copy(Circle&) const;
```

I know `const` after the function is used to tell the compiler that this function won't attempt to change the object it is called on, what about the other one?

Comment: that you won't change the parameter is the other

Answer (score 290):

The first form means that the (state of the) `Circle` object bound to the reference which is the parameter of the `copy()` function will not be altered by `copy()` through that reference. The reference is a reference to `const`, so it won't be possible to invoke member functions of `Circle` through that reference which are not themselves qualified as `const`.

The second form, on the other hand, is illegal: only **member functions** can be `const`-qualified (while what you are declaring there is a global, `friend` function).

When `const` qualifies a member function, the qualification refers to the implicit `this` argument. In other words, that function will not be allowed to alter the state of the object it is invoked on (the object pointed to by the implicit `this` pointer) - with the exception of `mutable` objects, but that's another story.

To say it with code:

```
struct X
{
    void foo() const // <== The implicit "this" pointer is const-qualified!
    {
        _x = 42; // ERROR! The "this" pointer is implicitly const
        _y = 42; // OK (_y is mutable)
    }

    void bar(X& obj) const // <== The implicit "this" pointer is const-qualified!
    {
        obj._x = 42; // OK! obj is a reference to non-const
        _x = 42; // ERROR! The "this" pointer is implicitly const
    }

    void bar(X const& obj) // <== The implicit "this" pointer is NOT const-qualified!
    {
        obj._x = 42; // ERROR! obj is a reference to const
        obj._y = 42; // OK! obj is a reference to const, but _y is mutable
        _x = 42; // OK! The "this" pointer is implicitly non-const
    }

    int _x;
    mutable int _y;
};
```

Comment: So, for the second case, if I have a `const` object `obj` of class `X`, and I call `bar()` like `obj.bar(obj)`, what is supposed to happen and why? Shouldn't `obj._x = 42` fail, since `obj` is declared `const` in the caller?

Comment: What about the case where you make the latter bar function (`void bar(X const& obj) {...}`) look like this? `void bar(const X& obj) {...}`, does moving the `const` keyword to this location change anything? If so, can you add this example too please?

Comment: @GabrielStaples They're the same; `const` applies to what is on its left, or to what is on its right in case there is nothing to the left. In your case you'll see that for both versions `const` is applied to `X`.

Comment: So nice answer, easy to understand

Answer (score 97):

C++ class methods have an implicit `this` parameter which comes before all the explicit ones.  So a function declared within a class like this:

```
class C {
  void f(int x);
```

You can imagine really looks like this:

```
  void f(C* this, int x);
```

Now, if you declare it this way:

```
  void f(int x) const;
```

It's as if you wrote this:

```
  void f(const C* this, int x);
```

That is, the trailing `const` makes the `this` parameter const, meaning that you can invoke the method on const objects of the class type, and that the method cannot modify the object on which it was invoked (at least, not via the normal channels).

Comment: Perfectly correct however it doesn't answer the question, which isn't actually referring to a class method but rather a friend function.

Comment: Yeah, I chose to ignore the `friend` part because I think it's actually irrelevant to the OP's real question (or what the real question will become once all the issues come to light).  So be it.

Comment: i think its slightly misleading to say "you can invoke the method on const objects of the class type" because you can invoke const method on const objects or non const objects, while non-const functions can only be called by non-const objects. otherwise this is my favorite answer

Answer (score 26):

---

**LET'S CLEAR ALL CONFUSION RELATED TO** **`const`**

---

**`const`** came from **constant** mean something is not changeable but readable.

1. if we qualify our variable with **`const`** keyword ,we can't change it later.
   e.g.
   **`const`**`int var =25;`     const variable must be initialized when it's declared.
   `var =50; // gives error`
2. if we qualify our pointer variable with **`const`** *after* **`*`** then we **can't** change pointer itself but content of pointer is **changeable**.
   e.g.
   `int *`**`const`** `ptr = new int;`
   `ptr = new int; //gives error`
   // but
   `*ptr=5445; //allowed`
3. if we qualify our pointer variable with **`const`** *before* **`*`** then we **can** change pointer itself but content of pointer is **not changeable**.
   e.g.
   `int`**`const`**`* ptr = new int(85);`
            `//or`       
   **`const`**`int * ptr = new int(85);`
   `ptr = new int; // allowed`
   // but
   `*ptr=5445; // gives error`
4. pointer and content both constant
   e.g.
   `int`**`const`**`*`**`const`**`ptr = new int(85);`
            `//or`                        
   **`const`**`int *`**`const`**`ptr = new int(85);`
   `ptr = new int; // not allowed`
   `*ptr=5445; // not allowed`

---

1. `Circle copy(const Circle &);`
   here const Circle means value of Circle is only readable ,if we try to change value of Circle inside function then it gives error.
2. `friend Circle copy(Circle&) const;`
   This type of function is not for non member variable .it is used for class or structure.
   Here whole function is qualified with const keyword means we can't change **object member variable** .
   e.g

```
    class A{ public :
              int  var;
              void fun1()
                    { var = 50; // allowed
                    } 
              void fun2()const
                       { var=50; //not allowed
                       }
           };
```

Answer (score 15):

```
Circle copy(Circle&) const;
```

makes the function `const` itself. This can only be used for member functions of a class/struct.

Making a member function `const` means that

- it *cannot* call any non-const member functions
- it *cannot* change any member variables.
- it can be called by a `const` object(`const` objects can only call `const` functions). Non-const objects can also call a `const` function.
- It *must* be member function of the class '**Circle**'.

Now consider the next one:

```
Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

while this one means that the parameter passed cannot be changed within the function. It may or may not be a member function of the class.

**NOTE:** It is possible to overload a function in such a way to have a `const` and non-const version of the same function.

Answer (score 5):

One refers to the parameter the other to the function.

```
Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

This means that the parameter passed in cannot be changed within the function

```
Circle copy(Circle&) const;
```

The `const` qualified function is used for member functions and means you cannot change the data members of the object itself. The example you posted was nonsensical.

#### Read right-to-left

If we rewrite the first function as `Circle copy(Circle const&);`, which means the same thing, it becomes clear that reading right to left becomes useful. *`copy` is a function that takes a `const` reference to a `Circle` object and returns a `Circle` object by reference.*

Answer (score 1):

`friend Circle copy(const Circle &);`//refers to constant parameter of the function. cant' change the value stored by parameter.

Need to remove friend in your example 
**Circle copy(Circle&) const;**
 //can't change this poniter value named as Constant member function

Answer (score 1):

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

The value of parameter will not be changed during the function calls.

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &)const ;
```

The function is an accessor that does not change any value of class members. Generally, there are to types of functions: accessors and mutators. 
Accessor: examines but does not change the state of its object.