# c++ function syntax/prototype - data type after brackets

Tags: c++, function, constants, mutable, function-signature

I am very familiar with C/C++ standard function declarations. I've recently seen something like this:

```
int myfunction(char parameter) const
```

The above is only a hypothetical example and I don't even know if it makes sense. I'm referring to the part AFTER the parameter. The const. What is this?

A more real example:

```
wxGridCellCoordsArray GetSelectedCells() const
```

This can be found [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxgrid.html#wxgridgetselectedcells)
So what exactly is that text `const` doing at the end of the line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999123/const-before-parameter-vs-const-after-function-name-c

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration)

Comment: @chris That's nice. But now I'm confused. The `GetSelectedCells` function has NO paramater to change?

Comment: @itsols, It's a member function. Therefore, it has a parameter.

Comment: Updated the answer to explain some important differences. First that adding const to the end of a function changes its signature and therefore is a valid overload of the function. Secondly, I explain why mutable is used and the difference between bitwise const and conceptual const along with a well written article explaining the difference. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The const keyword, when shown after a function, guarantees the function caller that no member data variables will be altered. It also changes the function signature, which is something less known to some C++ programmers. You can actually overload a function in C++ by adding the const keyword after a function with the same name. For example:

```
void changeValue() const;
void changeValue();
```

Both of the above functions are valid and an overload of each other. I often see some C++ API's and frameworks use this overload to avoid a plethora of compile errors when users call these functions within const and non-const functions. Whether this is good C++ software engineering is up for debate. I would imagine it is bad practice, but it is good to be aware that it changes the function signature.

For instance given this class,

```
// In header
class Node {

public:

Node();

void changeValue() const;

~Node();

private:

int value;

};
```

// in .cpp

```
void Node::changeValue() const {
    this->value = 3; // This will error out because it is modifying member variables
}
```

There is an exception to this rule. If you declare that a member data variable is mutable, then it can be altered regardless if the function is declared to be const. Using mutable is for the rare situation where an object is declared constant, but in practice has member data variables which need the option to change. One potential example of its use is caching a value that you may not want to repeat the original calculation. This is typically rare... But it is good to be aware of it. A good reference of software engineering decisions around Mutable is the concept of bitwise const vs conceptual const. With bitwise const, the programmer is informing the reader that when const is present, no bits for that const object shall change without a const_cast. With conceptual const, the idea is that the user of the class should not care whether the bits of the mutable variable should change as it does not impact the usage of the class from the user's perception. Here is a good article explaining the difference and the ups and downs of using Mutable - https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

For instance given this class,

```
// In header
class Node {

public:

Node();

void changeValue() const;

~Node();

private:

mutable int value;

};
```

// in .cpp

```
void Node::changeValue() const {
    this->value = 3; // This will not error out because value is mutable
}
```

Comment: Side effects include output, so that's not entirely true.

Comment: since your answer got accepted you should probably mention that you can change data members marked mutable then I'll throw you a +1

Comment: I come from the past :) My days with C go back to 1990. But I don't recall using this **mutable** keyword anywhere. It's been of no use to me. Why dould I need to do such a thing as state that something is a constant and then within the function say something is mutable? Don't quite get the reasons for these new things... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @itsols I forced him against his will to put it in, and I semi agree with you about the uselessness of the `mutable` keyword, c++ likes to let you do anything you want. Do you know about [`const_cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @itsols: An example of when you might want to use `mutable` is if your object had a "last access time" timestamp variable. You would want to be able to update that variable even when someone accessed the object with a `const` method.

Comment: I added a link explaining bitwise const vs conceptual const. This is what most C++ software engineers think about when deciding class architecture

Answer (score 8):

The const says that the function will not change any of the data members of `this` unless they are marked mutable.
Only a member function can be marked const so this means that none of the members will be changed inside the function.

Comment: Only exception to this is a const_cast. But, if anyone values their job I doubt they would use it =D

Answer (score 4):

It's a "defensive programming" technique to help guard against your own programming errors. With `const` against a function parameter, you are stating that the function should not modify that parameter, and adding the `const` causes the compiler to prevent you from inadvertently doing so. Similarly, if you write a member function which shouldn't change *any* member variables of your class, then you can declare the whole function `const` like that, and it will prevent you from doing so.

It also helps to make your code self-documenting. Adding `const` to a parameter tells a user that 'this function does not modify this parameter'. Adding `const` to a member function tells the user that 'this function does not modify any members of the class' (except explicitly mutable ones).

Restricting access to something except for those occasions where you really need it should generally be considered to be a good thing. It's the exact same reason why you don't routinely log onto your own system as root, even though you could, and you'd have more power if you did.

Comment: I like that - 'defensive' programming and self documenting. +1 for the tips

Answer (score 2):

The `const` keyword after a method means that the implicit `this` parameter (which is set to the address of the object used to invoke the method) points to a constant object.

In C++. a member function could look like:

```
class Foo {
    int x;
    mutable int y;
public:
    void bar ()       {
        Foo *me = this;          // * this is an implicit parameter
                                 //   that points to the instance used
                                 //   to call bar()
        assert(&x == &this->x);  // * accesses to class members are
                                 //   implicitly taken from this
        x = 1;                   // * can modify data members
    }
    void bar () const {
        // Foo *me = this;       // * error, since "bar() const" means
                                 //   this is a "const Foo *"
        const Foo *me = this;    // * ok
        // x = 1;                // * error, cannot modify non-mutable
                                 //   members of a "const Foo"
        y = 0;                   // * ok, since y is mutable
    }
};
```

The analog in C would be functions to access a `struct Foo *` and a `const struct Foo *`, respectively:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void Foo_bar (Foo *this)        { /* ... */ } /* can modify this->x and this->y */
void cFoo_bar (const Foo *this) { /* ... */ } /* cannot modify this->x nor this->y */
```

There is no `mutable` analog in C.