# Why not 'const T*' to 'T*' in MSVC error: Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const T' to 'T &'

Tags: c++

Edit: Please read the question. The suggested duplicates don't answer my question. (I already read those answers before posting this question.)

---

If compiling the code below, MSVC spits out a quite well-known error message `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const S' to 'S &'`.

We can remove the error by modifying the `S::f` into a `const` function, but my question is *why* the message is like that.

I thought the error message should be: `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const S*' to 'S*'`. Why it's `'const S'` to `'S &'`, not `'const S*'` to `'S*'`?

(I read some answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999170/10027592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067267/10027592), just for the context of my curiosity.)

```
struct S {
    void f(){}
};
int main() {
    const S s;
    s.f(); // 'void S::f(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const S' to 'S &' 
}
```

Comment: `int *p;` You say p is a pointer to `int`, you don't say it is a pointer to `int*`. So the phrase is correct. IDK why they use a reference. Better to ask directly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask/

Comment: *"my question is why the message is like that..."* This should be asked at msvc's official site. Stackoverflow is not the right place for seeking reasons why msvc uses potentially incorrect descirption of the error. You already seem to know that there should be no reference mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Just sloppy wording on Microsoft's part.

Comment: @jason So, do you think the error message is incorrect and there should be no `&` in the message(`S`, not `S&`)? Then what about the `*`? Let me know your opinion and that's why I asked this question. As a C++ beginner, I was just curious if I missed some concepts and didn't interpret the error message appropriately. I thought Stack Overflow is the place where learners can ask questions when they are not sure if they're doing things right... no? :) Anyway, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct S {
    void f(){}
};
```

The `f` method gets a default specifier `&`:

```
struct S {
    void f() & {}
};
```

Other non default specifiers are `&&`, `const` (that is `const&`) and `const&&`.

The method can be considered as a function that takes an object as a first parameter `void f(S&);` that accepts `S&` but gets `const S`, thus the error is pretty clear: `cannot convert ... from 'const S' to 'S &'`. Why `'this' pointer` still is a question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this concept, though. Are you talking about the _"member functions with ref-qualifier"_ in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)? Also, I thought typical member functions take `this` as a first (hidden) parameter, doesn't it? Do you mean `this` is `S&`?

Comment: Yes, the link is correct. `this` has a type `S*` or `const S*`.  Compilers don't deal with object names, they deal with addresses. If you look at Assembler, a reference function parameter `T& arg` or `const T& arg` takes an address of a passed object, so a function Assembler deals with a pointer `T* arg`.