# C++ Lambdas: Difference between "mutable" and capture-by-reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

In C++ you can declare lambdas for example like this:

```
int x = 5;
auto a = [=]() mutable { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; };
auto b = [&]()         { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; };
```

Both let me modify `x`, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### What is happening

The first will only modify its own copy of `x` and leave the outside `x` unchanged.
The second will modify the *outside `x`*.

Add a print statement after trying each:

```
a();
std::cout << x << "----\n";
b();
std::cout << x << '\n';
```

This is expected to print:

```
6
5
----
6
6
```

### Why

It may help to consider that lambda

> [...] expressions provide a concise way to create simple function objects

<sup>(see [expr.prim.lambda] of the Standard)</sup>

They have

> [...] a public inline function call operator [...]

which is declared as a `const` member function, but only

> [...] if and only if the lambda expression’s *parameter-declaration-clause* is not followed by `mutable`

You can think of as if

```
    int x = 5;
    auto a = [=]() mutable { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; };

==>

    int x = 5;

    class __lambda_a {
        int x;
    public:
        __lambda_a () : x($lookup-one-outer$::x) {}
        inline void operator() { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; }     
    } a;
```

and

```
    auto b = [&]()         { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; };

==>

    int x = 5;

    class __lambda_b {
        int &x;
    public:
        __lambda_b() : x($lookup-one-outer$::x) {}
        inline void operator() const { ++x; std::cout << x << '\n'; }         
        //                     ^^^^^
    } b;
```

**Q:** But if it is a `const` function, why can I still change `x`?

**A:** You are only changing *the outside `x`*. The lambda's own `x` is a reference, and the operation `++x` does not modify *the reference*, but *the refered value*.

This works because in C++, the constness of a pointer/reference does not change the constness of the pointee/referencee seen through it.

Comment: Nice and thorough.  But I think you have `a` some places you meant `b`.  And your objects of anonymous class type don't have initializers.  Might want to explain we're pretending `lambda_a()` is a constructor although the class has no name.

Comment: @aschepler: Thanks for the suggestions :) I changed to reserved names.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the constness? I didn't get a clear picture there. I think explaining what would happen if the 'const' was not present there would make it easy.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu: In the last example, the `const` actually makes no difference. You _always_ mutate the referencee through a reference. But to give another example: `int main () { int x; auto a = [=]() { ++x; }; }`. g++ will give an error message for that because the `[=]` means that the generated function object gets its own member variable `x`, but the lack of `mutable` means that a `const` member function call operator is generated, therefore the `x` is not assignable.

Comment: Excellent! +1 particularly for the above comment and _the constness of a pointer/reference does not change the constness of the pointee/referencee seen through it_. Adding this case `auto c = [=]() { ++x; };` above would give more clarity on why `mutable`, and there by `const`, makes a difference.

Comment: The real question is why the convention is taken in reverse compared to everything else in C++. `mutable` qualification should be by default, and `const` specification should be explicit.

Comment: @v.oddou Maybe because it is too easy to accidentally modify the capture by copy, e.g., `int sum = 0; std::for_each(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [sum](int x) { sum += x;})`.