# C++ parallel_for error

Tags: c++, tbb, function-object

I am trying to learn how to use TBB, so I'm modifying a sample program I found that is designed to compute powers of an array of complex numbers. Originally, it was passing an array into the parallel_for loop, but I am trying to change it so that it passes in a vector. However, I cannot get my code to compile; I get the following error (compiled using g++ -g program_name.cpp -ltbb):

```
error: passing ‘const std::complex<double>’ as ‘this’ argument
       discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] result[i] = z;
```

My code is below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_for_each.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;
typedef complex<double> dcmplx;

dcmplx random_dcmplx ( void )
{
   double e = 2*M_PI*((double) rand())/RAND_MAX;
   dcmplx c(cos(e),sin(e));
   return c;
}

class ComputePowers
{
   vector<dcmplx>  c; // numbers on input
   int d;           // degree
   vector<dcmplx>  result;  // output
   public:
      ComputePowers(vector<dcmplx> x, int deg, vector<dcmplx> y): c(x), d(deg), result(y) { }

      void operator() ( const blocked_range<size_t>& r ) const
      {
         for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i)
         {
            dcmplx z(1.0,0.0);
            for(int j=0; j < d; j++) {
                z = z*c[i];
            };
            result[i] = z;
         }
      }
};

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int deg = 100;
   int dim = 10;

   vector<dcmplx> r;
   for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
     r.push_back(random_dcmplx());

   vector<dcmplx> s(dim);

   task_scheduler_init init(task_scheduler_init::automatic);

   parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0,dim),
                ComputePowers(r,deg,s));
   for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
       cout << scientific << setprecision(4)
       << "x[" << i << "] = ( " << s[i].real()
       << " , " << s[i].imag() << ")\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case, you still did not understand the error, in your `operator()` method you are doing `result[I] = z;` . The method is marked as `const` and you are not supposed to modify the data members in methods marked as `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to modify non-`mutable` member field `result` in `const`-qualified `operator()`.

Resolve this discrepancy.

**Edit #1:** I have already mentioned the two keywords above. Either:

1. Remove `const` qualifier from `operator()`:

   ```
   void operator() ( const blocked_range<size_t>& r ) { ... }
   ```
2. Make `result` `mutable`:

   ```
   mutable vector<dcmplx> result;
   ```

Additional erorrs may emerge after applying (although **strongly preferred**) variant no. 1. No. 2 is just for completeness and is used only in [marginal situations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105014/3552770).

It indeed results in an error with the 1st variant. This is because `tbb::parallel_for` takes `Func` by `const&`, so it can call only `const`-qualified member functions on your functor. Why? TBB doesn't want to waste performance by copying large functors (STL passes them by value).

I don't know what's the common practice here, I've never used this library.

---

**Edit #2:** Probably all you were missing was that `result` wasn't a reference:

```
vector<dcmplx> &result;
```

Now you'll be able to modify it, even in `const`-qualified `operator()`. Modifying a member that gets destructed afterwards wouldn't make sense.

Don't forget to change the constructor's signature to pass `y` by reference, too.

---

Off topic issues in your code:

- Not included `<vector>` header
- `using namespace bulky_namespace` globally
- not using `size_t` for `i` in the `for`-loop
- maybe more...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm new to C++. How do I do this?

Comment: Thanks for your continued response. Does that mean that there's no way to make parallel_for modify a vector?

Comment: @Student This falls into *marginal cases*. `mutable` should work.

Comment: When I use `mutable` as you suggest, the code compiles and the modifications to the vector happen. However, the vector does not stay modified after the parallel_for loop finishes.

Comment: Oh, I see. `ComputePowers` with its members gets destructed shortly after... Which `std::vector` outside `ComputePowers` should be modified?

Comment: The `vector` outside that should be modified is `s`. I added in printing code to the original question to show that.

Comment: @Student Edit #2 is definitely your answer. However, I'll keep previous attempts of answering available for future reference.

Comment: The whole point of the const requirement is to be a compile-time reminder that `tbb::parallel_for` might copy the functor an arbitrary number of times, depending on the implementation.  Declaring it `mutable` just circumvents the reminder :-(.  Declare both `result` AND `c` as reference members, so that neither is copied each time tbb::parallel_for copies the functor.  Otherwise, the updates won't be seen in the original `result`, and each copying will cost O(N) time to copy an N-element vector.

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend learning how to use C++11 lambda expressions with capture-by-reference (i.e. `[&]`) with `tbb::parallel_for`.  Doing so makes the functors *much* easier to write.