# C++: Why can I pass a pointer-valued member variable from a const member function to an external function taking a non const pointer parameter?

Tags: c++

I am using a function from an external library (here represented by the `printer`-function).
By chance, I noticed, that I can pass a class member from a `const` member function like done by the `print()`-function. Even if I compile using

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -o test test.cpp
```

I don't obtain an error.

This seems to be horribly wrong, because effectively I am modifying the object by calling a `const` member function. Why is the compiler not complaining?
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printer(void* data) {
    static_cast<char*>(data)[0] = '1';
    cout << static_cast<char*>(data) << endl;
}

void setUp(char* data, int length) {
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        data[i] = '0';
    data[length] = '\0';
}

class Test {
    private:
        char* data;

    public:
        Test(int length) {
            data = new char(length+1);
            setUp(this->data, length);
        }

        ~Test() {
            delete data;
        }

        void print() const {
            printer(this->data);
        }
};

int main() {
    Test T(3);
    T.print();
    return 0;
}
```

My best guess is, that the compiler only guarantees, that the pointer variable is not modified, i.e. not pointing to a different physical address after the function call. But I also noticed, that the compiler throws errors when I try something similar with a `std::vector<char>` instead of `char*` and a modified `print`-function:

```
void print() const {
    printer(this->myVector.data());
}
```

So if my guess is correct, why is it not possible to do something similar with the pointer obtained by `data()` of a STL vector?

Comment: If you cast to `void*` you're discarding any `const` flags that apply. You're stepping outside of the usual type-checking rules.

Comment: there is no const external function.

Comment: Converting `std::vector<char>` to something you can print will require a `0` entry at the end that vector or it's not a valid C string.

Comment: Unrelated: typo in the example: `data = new char(length+1);` almost certainly should be `data = new char[length+1];`

Comment: @tadman, There's no cast to `void*`, though. There's an implicit conversion going on, but that conversion won't discard `const`. (I should clarify that exactly what I mean is that it won't convert `const char*` to `void*`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have a char* data member.
2. In the context of a const-qualified method, that means the *member* may not be mutated.
3. The member is the pointer. Changing a pointer means changing where it points.
4. Just to be clear, the effective qualified type inside the method is

   ```
    char * const
   ```

   and *not*

   ```
    const char *
   ```
5. Which is all to confirm that you're absolutely right that

   > My best guess is, that the compiler only guarantees, that the pointer variable is not modified, i.e. not pointing to a different ... address after the function call.

However, for the vector, you want to call data on something that again has effective qualified type `std::vector<char> const&` ... so you need the const-qualified overload of [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), and that returns `const char*`. This is what you expected in the first place, but it's not the same behaviour as the raw pointer.

The reason for the difference is that the vector was written to express ownership of that data, so a const vector should have const contents. Raw pointers *may* own the data they point at, but there's no way to express this, and no way to have different const behaviour for owning and non-owning raw pointers. This is one of the may reasons to avoid raw pointers where possible.

Comment: But shouldn't `std::vector::data` return also a `char* const`? The fact that is behaves differently seems a bit inconsistent. I know that there is no overload of `data()` that returns `char* const`; but wouldn't that be actually sufficient to satisfy the const-qualifier of `print()`?

Comment: No, it's a method and I linked to its documentation. You can see what it returns. There'd be no point in returning a const pointer, because you're returning it by value anyway. Here, vector's behaviour is both what you implied you wanted in the first place, and more correct for something that owns the data. The ambiguity about whether a raw pointer owns the object it points at (and the fact that const owning raw pointers don't make the pointee const) is one of the reasons that raw pointers are broadly discouraged.

Comment: Thank you, that was an incredibly helpful answer. I think it would be worthwhile to copy your comment beginning from "Here, vector's behaviour..." to the end of your answer, as it clarifies the design choice in std::vector and why it is reasonable to be different from the raw pointer case.

Comment: I didn't think that was what you were asking. Your question was about why the raw pointer _didn't_ have this behaviour, right? Not why the `vector` _did_?

Comment: Well, its not in the title, but the last sentence in my post is precisely that question.

Comment: This is why it's recommended to ask _one_ question per question. You actually asked _why can I do X, why does the compiler not complain about X, and why can't I do Y_. The first two are about the semantics of raw pointers, and the last is about the semantics of a library class that was designed to behave differently to raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common way of allowing a `const` method to change data.  The immutable thing in `Test` is the *pointer address* `data`; which is not altered by `print`.  You are nonetheless free to mutate what the pointer is addressing.

Another way round a `const` method is to declare a member as being `mutable`.  Arguably, ensuring an internal string attribute is e.g. null terminated for printing *could* be considered a legitimate use of `mutable`.

See this piece from Kate Gregory at CppCon 2017 where she provides an interesting example (a method is designed to be const but a cache is added later):
https://youtu.be/XkDEzfpdcSg?t=854

Also see this question for a lively discussion on the topic:
[Does the 'mutable' keyword have any purpose other than allowing the variable to be modified by a const function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105014/does-the-mutable-keyword-have-any-purpose-other-than-allowing-the-variable-to)