# msvc std::lower_bound requires const operator*

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I am getting a

```
Error   C2678   binary '*': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _InIt' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

it is thrown by this code in MSVC (2022, V17.1) `<algorithm>` header.

```cpp
template <class _FwdIt, class _Ty, class _Pr>
_NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 _FwdIt lower_bound(_FwdIt _First, const _FwdIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, _Pr _Pred) {

...
        const auto _UMid                   = _STD next(_UFirst, _Count2);
        if (_Pred(*_UMid, _Val)) { // try top half
```

The second line throws the error because of the `const` on the line above.

The iterator I am passing in, is a custom LegacyRandomAccessIterator over a "flat-file" and its `operator*` looks like this:

```cpp
  value_type operator*() { return current(); }

...

  ValueType current() {
    if (!cur_valid_) {
      cur_       = ffdb_->get_record(pos_);
      cur_valid_ = true;
    }
    return cur_;
  }
```

In other words, I can't just mark my `operator*` as `const` because it's not, and can't be really - It's doing loading of a buffered set of records from disk, and that's not a `const` operation in a the current design.

I implemented a "dummy" `const` version to prove that was the problem:

```cpp
 value_type operator*() const { return value_type{}; }
```

Error is gone, but clearly this doesn't do anything.

libstdc++ doesn't have this expectation of a `const operator*`.  (I haven't tested libc++)

Is this solvable, without some major redesign of my iterator?

Is it reasonable for MSVC's implementation to have this expectation?

Comment: Not sure if that's a legal iterator. How about moving `get_record` logic to `++`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's a thought. and to the constructor then..? for the iterator returned by begin() of the parent class?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: you could also make `cur_` & `cur_valid_` mutable, that way `current()` can be const.

Comment: @Turtlefight also neat idea...   I was just quite floored that there is the expectation to have a `const operator*`. Is that written somewhere that I have not seen?

Comment: Please note that the name of the template parameter is `_FwdIt`, so it requires a *forward iterator*, and for the forward iterator, the `operator*()` must be *equality-preserving*, that is, the values of the two calls before and after must be the same.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Sure. OK. I think I comply with that. Do you mean: If you call operator* twice it must give you the same value. It does. Just some internal private state has potentially changed (ie the buffered records).

Comment: If it's equiality-preserving, then making the variables mutable should be ok.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not 100% sure what equality preserving means exactly in this context... but yeah, I like the mutable idea. This seems to even suggest such usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/105061/1087626 " Logical const is when an object doesn't change in a way that is visible through the public interface"

Comment: After reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator), I'm not even sure it's the right term. Basically, repeated dereferences should return the same thing, until it's incremented.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Agreed. That's my interpretation too. And that will be true even if I "sneak past the const" by making `cur_` and `cur_valid_` `mutable`. Seems like the answer?

Comment: @康桓瑋 yeah. Like I said. It super surprised me. I have not seen `const operator*` in the various suggested iterator implementations.... My standardese is nowhere near good enough to say whether MSVC is "wrong" though.

Comment: Also note that in the C++17 iterator system, the return type of `operator*()` of forward iterator must be a reference type, so your iterator still does not model the forward iterator.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yeah, that may be true. And it can easily be a `&` to the private internal `cur_`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 The irony is that my iterator is a `const_iterator` in the sense that you can't modify the values on disk via the reference you would get from `operator*`. But the iterator object itself is "not const" if that makes sense.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock *"Is [the expectation to have a `const operator*`] written somewhere that I have not seen?"* -- See [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator). Given `i`, a value of type `It` **or `const It`**, the expression `*i` must be valid.

Comment: just move `ffdb_->get_record(pos_)` et. al. into the increment operator and let `operator*` be truly const.

Comment: @JaMiT OK, that's good...  For clarity.. this is actually a random access iterator... otherwise not much point calling std::lower_bound. ... binary search ...

Comment: @jwezorek That could also work. I just don't like the fact that it would then have to make `cur_` valid immediately upon construction, ie when you call `begin()`  on the parent class.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock You asked about what `std::lower_bound` requires. It requires a _LegacyForwardIterator_, and a _LegacyForwardIterator_ must satisfy _LegacyInputIterator_. This requirement does not change based upon what you intend your iterator to be. (Still, if you intend your iterator to be a _LegacyRandomAccessIterator_, then it must also be a _LegacyBidirectionalIterator_, which in turn requires being a _LegacyForwardIterator_, and we're back to satisfying _LegacyInputIterator_.)

Comment: @JaMiT Yes I understand all that. Thank you. I thought it was worth mentioning that the requirements on the iterator are actually a significant SUPERSET LegacyForwardIterator. Beause of what it is doing in the application, not because of std::lower_bound. Although std::lower_bound is quite pointless if you feed it with a FWdIt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` takes a *Cpp17ForwardIterator*, which must also be a *Cpp17InputIterator*.  The *Cpp17InputIterator* [requirements include](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#tab:inputiterator):

| Expression | Return type |
| --- | --- |
| `*a` | `reference`, convertible to `T` |

Here, `a` is a ["value of type `X` or `const X`"](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#iterator.cpp17.general-1), so MSVC is justified in requiring a const-qualified unary indirection operator; the "or" means that the code using the iterator can use either, and the author of the iterator has to support both. (Note that *Cpp17InputIterator* differs from *Cpp17OutputIterator*, where the required operation is `*r = o`, with `r` a non-const reference, `X&`.)

So your `operator*` should have `const` qualification, and return a reference; specifically, a reference to `T` or `const T` (this is [a *Cpp17ForwardIterator* requirement](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#forward.iterators-1.3)).  You can satisfy this straightforwardly with `using reference = const T&` and by making `cur_`  and `cur_valid_` `mutable`.

The use of `mutable` here is entirely legitimate; since `operator*() const` is idempotent, it is "logically const" and the modifications to the data members are non-observable.